# How to know where the linker is looking for a lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I'am getting a linkage error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'xpcomglue_staticruntime.lib'
1>Project : warning PRJ0018 : The following environment variables were not found:
1>$(GRE_HOME)
```

When I'm looking in project->properties->Linker->additional library directories I see there:

```
$(GRE_HOME)\..\lib
```

My question: how can i know where the linker is looking for the libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who wrote the project had an environment variable named `GRE_HOME` which is a directory path. You should set this env variable in your computer to the directory about `lib` (where this lib is located). You'll need to close and open VS for the changes in env variables to take effect.